# Word 16 document is opening in Locked mode

Tags: asp.net, office365

i'm Opening Word File from my Application in HTTP Path
i.e. http:\Server\SiteName\TempFiles\filename.docx

Word File Showing message as "READ ONLY : This Document is Lock for Editing by another user"

because of this my macro didn't work

```
Protection = ActiveDocument.ProtectionType
       If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType = wdAllowOnlyFormFields Then
           ActiveDocument.Unprotect "password"
           WordBasic.AcceptAllChangesInDoc
           ActiveDocument.Protect Protection, False, "password"
           Call updateCustomVariables
           ActiveDocument.Saved = True
           Exit Sub
       End If
```

every thing is working fine
and still working fine on office (Word) 13,10 machines
this problem suddenly start from last 3- 4 days 
i'm getting error as Command failed (Run time Error 4198) for office 16 for   ActiveDocument.Unprotect "password" line 
no office Updates
no windows update 
please help..

Check trusted Location Setting of Word i.e. Allow documents from Network to be trusted 
disable all Protected View options

Comment: Does rebooting your PC help?

Comment: machine or server ? the problem observed for all machines(Client) having office 16

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an answer but I'm new here and can't comment yet ;)

Got the same problem with one of our customers. Issue appeared in the latest Office 365 monthly rollout (16.0.11901.20264) a few days ago. The semi-annual version (16.0.11328.20362) doesn't have the issue. Our files are served using a URL with parameters. With previous versions of office it displays Read Only in the title bar but allows the user to edit the content.

With the new monthly version there is a read-only message that displays under the ribbon with a link to Save As. User cannot change the document content unless he saves the file locally. Even worse Word makes requests without the parameters so our code abends. I changed the code locally to put the parameter information in the path and I can open the document. But it still says that it's locked and the user can't edit the content.

We open and manage documents them using a VSTO side panel so we don't need to save them using the Save button. The application has it's own Save button that retrieves the updated content, saves it using an AJAX call and closes Word. Nice change of behavior from MS ;)

Comment: No problem! I've actually submitted an issue to MS and they replied. We'll see but I don't expect a quick turnaround. I changed our Word URLs to pass the request identifier in the path. Solves the parameter issue. As for the read only one I've changed our VSTO editor panel to do a save as in the user's temp folder. When the document is closed I delete the file if the he didn't save it somewhere else.

Comment: can you explain ,how you implement   "We open and manage documents them using a VSTO side panel so we don't need to save them using the Save button. The application has it's own Save button that retrieves the updated content, saves it using an AJAX call and closes Word"

Comment: By the way the two bugs are fixed in the latest build of the Monthly Channel version! As for the edition it's a little long to explain. But basically we launch Word using an Office URL. It returns the content and injects a VSTO application. Both communicate using SignalR. The VSTO just runs a Web Browser Component on the right and navigates to a URL that is supplied in the Document Properties. That URL is part of the originating web application. On Save we do an AJAX call to update the document, signal that we're done and close Word.